# pr2_arm_kinematics wrong md5 after upgrade, strange folders and compile errors on pr2 core packages

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using [pr2_control_utilities](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_control_utilities) for some time and they are quite robust to changes in msgs and APIs. However yesterday, after an upgrade (I am running fuerte), the md5 of **kinematics_msgs/GetPositionIK** changed. Although I recompiled my code (it's in python, don't really know if it matters doing rosmake), the problem persisted. I've tried several make clean - make iterations on several packages. Here is the error that pr2_arm_kinematics reported:

client wants service /pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_ik to have md5sum 877eea62385e0e095b5756ea4386623d, but it has 6d82fcb918d48c6d8a708bc55e34ace2. Dropping connection.

However if I do

> rossrv md5
> kinematics_msgs/GetPositionIK

I get 877eea62385e0e095b5756ea4386623d, so I though the client was right and the service provider **pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware** had the wrong md5. Since this is obtained using apt-get I assumed that it was correctly compiled and linked. I tried to manually compile it, but I got the error:

> [ 50%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware_lib.dir/src/pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware.o
> /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_kinematics/pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware.cpp:44:35:
> fatal error: kinematics_msgs/utils.h:
> No such file or directory so something
> really strange is going on.

The kinematics_msgs folder only has the content:

> cmake  manifest.xml  msg  srv

And the generated messages are somewhere else, namely /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kinematics_msgs/srv.

What is the right md5? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After some digging I found that the file arm_navigation/kinematics_msgs/srv_gen/cpp/include/kinematics_msgs/GetPositionIK.h has md5sum:

6d82fcb918d48c6d8a708bc55e34ace2

However in opt/ros/fuerte/include/kinematics_msgs/GetPositionIK.h it has:

877eea62385e0e095b5756ea4386623d

Same goes for the python and lisp files. I don't know why there's these repetitions of messages but it's creating confusion and mismatching problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39276/pr2_arm_kinematics-wrong-md5-after-upgrade,-strange-folders-and-compile-errors-on-pr2-core-packages/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only way you should have gotten kinematics_msgs in /opt/ros/fuerte/include is through installing ros-fuerte-moveit-msgs.  It currently in the case that you can't really have this package installed and use arm_navigation at the same time.  We'll try to figure out a way for these systems to co-exist, but for now I'd recommend de-installing moveit if you want to use arm_navigation.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2012-07-19**:
You're right!!! Thanks you saved my day! This should be written in bold face somewhere, it gave me big headaches in a very subtle way!

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-19**:
Would it be possible to mark the .deb packages as conflicting each other? Then only one can be installed at a time!

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2012-07-19**:
That would be the best solution.